# Character encoding JasperReports 5.6.0

Tags: java, character-encoding, jasper-reports

How can I set charecter encondig before export the report?

Before version 5.6.0

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

With the new version, how can I set?

Comment: +1 I am looking for an answer as well. I guess we need to use a configuration, but cant find the details.

Comment: Anybody? I can't resolve this.

Comment: I would guess you already have, but maybe you get more luck at jasperreports forums.

Comment: I already posted my question on jasperreports forums and nobody answer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after not  receive response, finally I found the answer:

```
ExporterOutput reportOutput;
reportOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(reportFile,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Where reportFile is the url string of my new file and the encoding just put as the second parameter of the constructor. This works only for HTML exporting.

Answer (score 1):

the API sais:

> `JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING` is deprecated.
>
> Replaced by
>
> `SimpleWriterExporterOutput.SimpleWriterExporterOutput(java.io.File, String)`,
>   `SimpleWriterExporterOutput.SimpleWriterExporterOutput(String, String)`
>   and
>   `SimpleWriterExporterOutput.SimpleWriterExporterOutput(java.io.OutputStream, String)`.

The property itself has following docu:
public static final java.lang.String PROPERTY_CHARACTER_ENCODING
Deprecated. Replaced by WriterExporterOutput.PROPERTY_CHARACTER_ENCODING.

see following link http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html

Comment: Well nice, for any exporter using  WriterExporterOutput, but what can we do, if we use a JRPdfExporter which uses OutputStreamExporterOutput.